# How do I make my image insert in the circle and get centered in the .s-circles-1

Tags: html, css

How do I make my image gets centered in the `.s-circles-1` `<div>`...

Html

```css
.s-circles-1 {
display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.1;
    margin-left: 315px;
    margin-top: 155px;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 164px;
    height: 164px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.s-img-1 {
    opacity: 0.9;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    color: #E37218;
    margin-right: 70vw;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="services">
   <div class="s-text">
     <h2>Services</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="s-circles-1">
     <img src="/Shapes/code (1).svg" alt="" class="s-img-1">
   </div>
 </div>
```

I am trying to make my image get inserted in the circle.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please try to make sure you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.php

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

With background-image :

```css
 div.circle {
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 164px;
  aspect-ratio : 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
   <div class="s-text">
      <h2>Services</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="circle" style="background-image: url(https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image)"></div>
</div>
```

---

With your code, you need to change your css with this (if you don't want to use background-image) :

- s-circles-1 class : set `overflow:hidden;`
- s-img-1 class : set
  `width:100%;` and `height:100%;`

```css
.s-circles-1 {
display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width: 164px;
    aspect-ratio:1 / 1; /* Keep the same width */
    border-radius: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.s-circles-1 img {
    opacity: 0.9;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
   <div class="s-text">
     <h2>Services</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="s-circles-1">
     <img src="https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/image" alt="">
   </div>
 </div>
```

---

With your code, but if your image is not a square :

```css
div.circle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 164px;
  aspect-ratio : 1 / 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.circle img {
  /*if width > height*/
  height: 164px;
  /*if height > width*/
  /*width: 164px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
  <div class="s-text">
    <h2>Services</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1200x500/000/fff" alt="" class="circle">
  </div>
</div>
```